# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown' in Cross-validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to divide some data with Cross-validation the set x and y work correctly but when entering

```
clf = svm.SVC (kernel = 'linear', C = 1).fit (X_train, y_train)
```

it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

please help.

Code is below:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import svm

x= sms['spam lda_predict8'.split()]
y=sms.spam

def my_train_test_split(x,y):
    # split data train 70 % and test 30 %
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,train_size=0.3,random_state=42)
    #normalization
    x_train_N = (x_train-x_train.mean())/(x_train.max()-x_train.min())
    x_test_N = (x_test-x_test.mean())/(x_test.max()-x_test.min())

my_train_test_split(x,y)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: can you please post full error?

Comment: also, it seems that the problem is about labels (y) can you post your labels? does your labels include any label called “unknown”?